# Drag a line from center in swift, makes it jump around

Tags: swift, math, uikit

I am trying to create a LineSegment struct that will be able to be drawn in any view, and also I want to change its values with a Pan gesture recognizer.

I did it, and it works, BUT it jumps around when I try to drag it from the center.

```html
<div class="cloudapp-embed" data-slug="1V3q0s420Q2t"><script async src="https://embed.cl.ly/embedded.gz.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>
```

```
public struct LineSegment {

var a: CGPoint!
var b: CGPoint!

var center: CGPoint! {
    get {
        let centerDistance = a.distance(to: b) / 2
        return getPointOnLineWithDistaceFromA(centerDistance)
    }
    set (newCenter) {
        let axOffset = newCenter.x - a.x
        let ayOffset = newCenter.y - a.y
        let bxOffset = newCenter.x - b.x
        let byOffset = newCenter.y - b.y
        let newa = CGPoint(x: newCenter.x + axOffset, y: newCenter.y + ayOffset)
        let newb = CGPoint(x: newCenter.x + bxOffset, y: newCenter.y + byOffset)
        self.a = newa
        self.b = newb
    }
}

var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer? = nil
var dragRadius: CGFloat = 30

init(a: CGPoint, b:CGPoint) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
}
}
extension LineSegment {

func getPointOnLineWithDistaceFromA(_ distance: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let d = a.distance(to: b)
    let t = distance / d
    let newP = CGPoint(x: (1 - t) * a.x + t * b.x, y: (1 - t) * a.y + t * b.y)
    return newP
}

/// Grabs the closes point and moves it to 'to'
mutating func grabClosestPoint(to: CGPoint, grabCenter: Bool = false) {
    if to.distance(to: a) < self.dragRadius {
        self.a = to
    } else if to.distance(to: b) < self.dragRadius {
        self.b = to
    } else if grabCenter && to.distance(to: self.center) < self.dragRadius {
        self.center = to
    }
}
}
```

I call the "grabClosestPoint" function with panGesture.

I do not know what is the problem, ether the math is wrong, or there is some UI problem that I can't figure out...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out. The math was wrong.

```
let axOffset = newCenter.x - a.x
let ayOffset = newCenter.y - a.y
let bxOffset = newCenter.x - b.x
let byOffset = newCenter.y - b.y
let newa = CGPoint(x: newCenter.x + axOffset, y: newCenter.y + ayOffset)
let newb = CGPoint(x: newCenter.x + bxOffset, y: newCenter.y + byOffset)
self.a = newa
self.b = newb
```

This is not only translating the edges, but also reversing them. So i changes it to:

```
 let centerOffsetX = newCenter.x - self.center.x
 let centerOffsetY = newCenter.y - self.center.y
 let newa = CGPoint(x: a.x + centerOffsetX, y: a.y + centerOffsetY)
 let newb = CGPoint(x: b.x + centerOffsetX, y: b.y + centerOffsetY)
 self.a = newa
 self.b = newb
```

Now it works great.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you didnt declare the distance variable anywhere, so it breaks the code